# PHP - Upload file to S3 Bucket using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Mumbai Server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

Currently I have working on System build by using which has been migrate from Godaddy to Amazon AWS. We have also use S3 Bucket for storing images or other file. Our Server location is Mumbai. Our system is working nicely on amazon, but I have facing problem in File upload to S3 Bucket.

I have follow this code for upload file to S3 Bucket Server. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html.

But by using this code from form we can send only image or file directly upload to S3 Bucket.

But I have want to upload file to S3 Bucket via my php code not directly upload html form to S3 Bucket. Because with file or image we want to insert form data to mysql server also.

If anyone has some idea to how can we upload file to s3 bucket via php code with submitting form data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Donovan Schönknecht*'s PHP class to upload it to S3. It can be cloned from [this](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/) git.

You can process with your file/image before applying some [object operations](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class#object-operations) to push it to S3 bucket.

---

In addition, if you need to process your image before uploading it to bucket, you can use [this](https://github.com/VijayaSankarN/Image-Processor-with-S3-upload) repository that processes the images before uploading it to desired AWS S3 bucket

Comment: Thanks for this response but when I have already use this class and I have face this error message - Message: S3::putObject(): [InvalidRequest] The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: May be you can check this [issue](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/pull/128) and try a work around

Comment: By using issue link, but now I have face new error like - "The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent"

Comment: @NarayanKartikey can you confirm the exact wording of that error message, please?  Also, what is the region in which your bucket is located?

Comment: I have follow https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/pull/128/commits/32afaa460de825f32df1790a0acbb562653d5886 this link and make require changes in my S3.php class. After making changes I have received this error - "The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent".

Comment: My S3 Bucket Server is located at Mumbai Region - s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Thanks Thamilan, I have solved problem by using your link https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/pull/128 and follow instruction and I have succeed upload file to s3 bucket.

Comment: But can any one help me how can I display uploaded image from S3 bucket to web page, because in bucket I have set permission private. So How can I display private image from S3 Bucket to Webpage...